# Javascript não recebe json response do Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, laravel-5

Estou tentando fazer o Javascript receber os dados enviados pelo servidor e jogar no alert. Mas sempre vem undefined. Já olhei muitos tópicos sobre isso na internet e não achei nada de errado no código. Em teoria era para funcionar. Alguém consegue me ajudar? Obrigado

Aqui está o código do JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $( "#enviar" ).click(function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var email = $('#email').val();  
        var nome = $('#nome').val();
        var telefone = $('#telefone').val();
        var msg = $('#msg').val();
        $( "#cont-form" ).html('<div class="loader" id="load"><img src="img/loader.gif"></div>');
        $.ajax({
                url : '/send',
                method : 'POST',
                data : { msge: msg, mail: email, tel: telefone, name: nome, _token: token},
                success: function(data){
                    $( "#cont-form" ).html('<div class="enviada"><h1>Mensagem enviada!</h1></div>');
                    $('.enviada').hide();
                    $('.enviada').slideDown();
                    alert(data.test);
                }
        });
    });

});
```

Aqui está a parte do controller que recebe a requisição:

```
public function enviar(Request $request) {
        $msg = $request['msge'];
        $nome = $request['name'];
        $email = $request['mail'];
        $telefone = $request['tel'];
        if ($telefone == '') {
            $telefone = 'Numero não informado';
        }
        $enviar = new Emails();
        $enviar->enviarEmail($nome, $email, $telefone, $msg);

    }
```

E por último a classe que envia o email:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class Emails extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function enviarEmail($nome, $email, $telefone, $msg)
    {
        $title = $nome;
        $content = $msg;
        $info = [
            'nome'  => $nome,
            'email' => $email
        ];
        Mail::send('emails.send', ['title' => $title, 'content' => $content, 'telefone' => $telefone], function ($message) use($info)
        {

            $message->from($info['email'], $info['nome']);

            $message->to('email@gmail.com')->subject('Mensagem do Site');

        });

        return response()->json(['test' => 'Request completed']);
    }
}
```

Comment: O retorno do response deve estar no controlador, apenas adicione um return no final do seu controller desta forma: `return $enviar;` Sempre quem dá os retornos ao cliente é o controlador, as outras sempre retornarão para as classes que a chamaram, tipo: Emails está retornando para Controller.

Comment: Eu ja tentei isso antes de postar a pergunta e não deu certo...

Comment: Eu até hoje só utilizei a 4.2, lá não existe o helper `response`, mas possivelmente seja igual, por padrão o laravel já retorna arrays como json, tente retornar apenas a array(no controller), e outra coisa que você pode ver, é dar um log apenas no `data` e ver o que tem nele.

Comment: Já dei. Tudo que retorna é o valor de $('#email').val();

Comment: Embora os dados do formulário sejam enviados corretamente para o e-mail do destinatário

Comment: Agora que percebi que brisei ao dizer pra retornar o $enviar, ele retornaria o objeto Email, é preciso passar o retorno do enviarEmail para uma variavel, tente o seguinte: `$response = $enviar->enviarEmail($nome, $email, $telefone, $msg);` e de o return do `$response` no Controller.

Comment: Consegui, amigo. Obrigado.

Comment: De nada, aqui diz pra não usar o comentário para dar resposta, então estou colocando uma, se bem que não vou conseguir explicar muito bem, mas já deve ser de ajuda caso alguém venha a ter uma dúvida parecida.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com as informações dadas nos comentários, foi possível descobrir a causa do problema.
A função `enviarEmail` da classe `Emails` está retornando um `response` para o controlador com os dados que quer que sejam recebidos pelo JSON.

Porém o controlador não está dando o retorno desse `response`, pois quem dá o resultado em texto para a view é a primeira classe chamada pelo router* (aquela definida no arquivo de rotas).

Seria necessário dar o retorno desse `response` da seguinte forma no *controller*:

```
return $enviar->enviarEmail($nome, $email, $telefone, $msg);
```

Adicionando o `return` na função`enviarEmail` do objeto `$enviar`, ou repassando para outra variavel (apenas para facilitar a leitura):

```
$response = $enviar->enviarEmail($nome, $email, $telefone, $msg);
return $response;
```

* Desculpe qualquer erro, não tenho informação melhor/exatadeste funcionamento, não cheguei a ver a fundo como isso funciona no fonte do Laravel, é uma dedução.